# Is $ n \sum \rho_i^2 \geq (\sum \rho_i)^2$?

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, cauchy-schwarz-inequality, triangle-inequality

Say I have a real-valued vector $\rho$ of length $n$. Is the following inequality always true?

$n \sum \rho_i^2 \geq (\sum \rho_i)^2$

I originally thought this was a trivial triangle inequality like property, but I am having an embarrassingly hard time proving it.

Comment: Yes, this is Cauchy-Schwarz: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality

Comment: @CheeHan Sorry I'm probably just being dense but here there is only one vector. Using the Cauchy Schwartz inequality, which states $\sum(uv) ^2 \leq \sum(u^2) \sum(v^2)$, and plugging in u for v, I'm left with a trivial identity. I'm probably just missing something incredibly obvious. Is this a corollary of CS or is it literally the same statement.

Comment: The Cauchy-Schwarz inequality tells us $$ \sum_{j=1}^n u_j v_j \leq \left(\sum_{j=1}^n u_j^2 \right)^{1/2} \left( \sum_{j=1}^n v_j^2 \right)^{1/2}. $$ If we square both sides, we obtain $$ \left(\sum_{j=1}^n u_j v_j \right)^2 \leq \left(\sum_{j=1}^n u_j^2 \right)\left( \sum_{j=1}^n v_j^2 \right).  $$ Finally, put $u_j=\rho_j$ and $v_j=1$ to obtain the desired inequality.

Comment: Or, if you prefer [Jensen's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen%27s_inequality#Finite_form):
$$\left(\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n\rho_i}n\right)^2\le\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{\rho_i^2}n.$$

Comment: Or Hölder with $p=2$ :)